# How to add custom authentication alongside OAuth authentication to ASP.NET MVC 4 application?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth

Within an ASP.NET MVC 4 application, is there a recommended approach for allowing users to login via a username/password (stored in the database) and/or via OAuth (e.g. their twitter or facebook account)?

Ideally, I'd like to allow users the option of either approach and the ability to associate multiple OAuth identities should they want to, so that they could login multiple way.  If users go the traditional route of providing a username and password, I'll also need the ability to add the usual features like "Forgot Password", etc....

This is an existing application I'm looking to add this functionality too.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but this is built in to a default ASP.NET MVC 4 internet template.

Comment: I have to work with an existing Users table and so I am looking for something that wouldn't require me having to work with the built-in membership, roles, and profile crud.